# why am I getting old mentions in jtwitter?

Tags: android, jtwitter

I am using jtwitter to get the user's latest mentions (using the code below) but the earliest mention I'm getting is 20 days old.

```
twitter.getMentions();
```

I am getting the timeline and DMs correctly.

Is anyone saw that problem before and can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the max result to 20 and it solved
i don't know why that problem even accured because the default is 20 anyway

Answer (score 0):

As I know `twitter.getMentions()` returns the last 20 updates by default. You can increase this number using `setMaxResults` method. Also you can use setSinceDate and setSinceId methods.

More you can find [here](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/).

Comment: thanks for your answer  but that is not my problem. the problem is that i'm getting wrong values  even without setting any parameters

Comment: Can you then clarify the question?

Comment: instead of getting the latest results (i.e. about 1h ago) i'm getting old results (i.e. 20 days ago). however the timeline and the DMs are correct so i probably doing something wrong with getmantions()

Comment: Then, I suppose you set somewhere the first id message using method setSinceId.

Comment: and then it will give me the first 20 after it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you fix setSinceId it will return you first 20 mentions after the fixed id.

Comment: i just checked. didn't use the setsinceid anywhere.. but the problem is fixed by set the max result to 20. @Yury thanks anyway